# Where is this space on the right side of my page coming from?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Yesterday, I noticed a large space on the right hand side of my WordPress website. I haven't made any CSS or HTML changes recently, so I'm not sure that styling is to blame. I've tried deactivating all of the plugins on the site, but that hasn't had any effect.

[My website](https://www.coaster101.com)

It appears that the problem is limited to Chrome, specifically when looking at the site on a desktop. On Mobile and other browsers, website appears unaffected.

I can generally troubleshoot most issues like this with Chrome's Inspect tool, but this one has left me scratching my head.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: For me the page looks normal in latest Chrome

Comment: I would consider adding a screenshot of what you're referring to as well as any details of any code/inspector investigations you may have done.

Comment: look for div id=page, on the following div you have div class='container' you have max-width:1460px and also margin:0 auto.  Those are causing you your problem

Answer (score 0):

The `.s2` calss has a rule of `float: right;` removing the float rule should solve your issue. Try it in your browser as per the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: While that removes the scroll bar, the sidebar itself is pushed down. Here's a screenshot: https://imgur.com/hlrC21P